# Best practice for npm modules

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I have a project that requires some shared code, we basically have 2 types of client APIs and some similar functionality, call them `client1` and `client2`. We have a project that has 4 directories, one for each client and library directories for api-common and api-logic. Each one has its own `package.json` with their respective dependencies and both `client1` an `client2` include the following:

```
"api-common": "file:../libs/api-common",
"api-logic": "file:../libs/api-logic",
```

Currently everyone of these modules includes a build script that transpiles into EC2015 using babel:

```
"build": "babel src -d dist",
```

For some reason `npm install` appears flaky. At times we find a run of `npm install` under the `api-logic` project (which depends on `api-common`) will fail:

```
npm ERR! path /home/user/workspace/server/libs/api-logic/node_modules/.staging/minimist-bb10354d
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/home/user/workspace/server/libs/api-logic/node_modules/.staging/minimist-bb10354d' -> '/home/user/workspace/server/libs/api-common/node_modules/rc/node_modules/minimist'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
```

This doesn't really make much sense to me. I've already run `npm install` inside of `api-common`. It installed fine. I can see `api-common/node_modules/rc/node_modules/minimist` exists. Is there a better way of doing this? For some reason I get the feeling I should not be running babel until the very end when building `client1` and `client2`.

Any help on best practices of code sharing within npm modules would be greatly appreciated. I'm very new to npm, so please assume nothing is obvious :)